# boost serialization for the std::list type varaible not working

Tags: c++, serialization, c++11, boost, boost-serialization

how do i serialize the std::allocator type in struct and for reference please see the below code as example :

//SimpleData.hpp

```
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/optional.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>

namespace A
{

    struct FullData 
    {
        FullData();
        FullData(const parameter_strings & parms);

        virtual ~FullData();

        std::string country;
        int pincode;

        private :
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
            void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
            {      
                ar & country;
                ar & pincode;
            } 

         typedef std::list<FullData> FullDataInfo; // what should be done to serialize this data 
    };

}

// SimpleData.cpp
#include "SimpleData.hpp" 
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>

namespace A
{
    FullData::FullData()
    {

    }

    FullData::~FullData()
    {

    }

    FullData::FullData(const parameter_strings & parms): detail(parms)
    {

        // impelmentation
    }

}

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(A::FullData)
BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(A::FullData    , boost::serialization::object_serializable)
BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING(A::FullData          , boost::serialization::track_never)
```

I don't know how to serialize the **typedef FullData::inst_list FullDataInfo;**

Thanks,

Comment: A definition of `inst_list` seems to be missing from the above code.  Please test your code by making a http://sscce.org so we can understand you -- compiling code (or almost compiling code, if your problem is a compiler error) is a lot easier to understand than remote reading of your mind!

Comment: Ok.  Now what have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: @user3382670 This has [been the sixth time I have cleaned up the mess that your questions contained](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bboost%5D+parameter_strings+is%3Aquestion), in about a month time. Yet, every single time you post a new question, it contains the same annoying errors. If you can't use the information you're getting in the answers, maybe you should consider abandoning the project. This has been the last time I've made up a definition for `parameter_strings` for you.

Comment: We are not the only ones who can write self-contained example programs. You could have copied one from any of the answers you've received. Not doing so indicates extreme laziness or incompetence. It's okay to learn, but if you can't manage asking questions in a fruitful manner you're simply aiming to high. (I hope you don't actually store pincodes unprotected in an archive.)

Comment: i take care from next time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just write the code:

```
int main()
{
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);

    A::FullData data1({ { "key1", "value1" }, { "key2", "value2" } });
    data1.pincode = 1234;
    data1.country = "ES";
    A::FullData data2({ { "key3", "value3" }, { "key4", "value4" } });
    data2.pincode = 4321;
    data2.country = "UK";

    A::FullData::FullDataInfo list { data1, data2 };

    oa << list;
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab79cb4f4e93776b)**

Output:

```
22 serialization::archive 10 0 0 2 0 2 ES 1234 2 UK 4321
```

Full Code Listing

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/optional.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>

namespace A
{
    typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> parameter_strings;
    struct FullData 
    {
        FullData() : pincode(0) {}
        FullData(const parameter_strings & parms) : pincode(0), detail(parms) {}

        virtual ~FullData() {}

        std::string country;
        int pincode;

      private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
            void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned int)
            {      
                ar & country;
                ar & pincode;
            } 

         parameter_strings detail;

      public:
         typedef std::list<FullData> FullDataInfo; // what should be done to serialize this data 
    };

}

// SimpleData.cpp
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(A::FullData)
BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(A::FullData    , boost::serialization::object_serializable)
BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING(A::FullData          , boost::serialization::track_never)

int main()
{
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);

    A::FullData data1({ { "key1", "value1" }, { "key2", "value2" } });
    data1.pincode = 1234;
    data1.country = "ES";
    A::FullData data2({ { "key3", "value3" }, { "key4", "value4" } });
    data2.pincode = 4321;
    data2.country = "UK";

    A::FullData::FullDataInfo list { data1, data2 };

    oa << list;
}
```